# Edit a MySQL value on insert if the email address already exists

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following MySql insert

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO newsletters(`email`, `name`, `subscribed_gdpr`)VALUES('$emailclean','$nameclean','$radio_value')");
```

My database structure is like this id *(which is auto increment)*, name, email, subscribed_gdpr, created *(date the entry was created)*, modified *(date the entry was modificed)*

I would like that if a user enters an email address that already exists to update the field `subscribed_gdpr` with the current submited radio value (it can have two values, Yes or No)

Thanks!

Comment: Create a unique key on `email`, and use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: GDPR plus SQL injection holes. Oh no.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 0):

As long as email is a unique key update your SQL as follows:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO newsletters(`email`, `name`, `subscribed_gdpr`)
                   VALUES('$emailclean','$nameclean','$radio_value')
                   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `subscribed_gdpr` ='$radio_value'");
```

Comment: [PHP strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) can and will interpolate variables. Switching to concatenation doesn't fix any problems. The `ON DUPLICATE KEY` part is the answer here, the rest is dangerous code from the original question.

Comment: I wasn't trying to fix any problems with my answer just show him the complete syntax for including the on duplicate key.

Comment: It's probably better to match styles or flip to placeholders to keep things consistent. I was a little quick to judge at first because *so many* PHP devs thing using concatenation fixes things, so sorry about that.